# French equivalent of "Granted/Sure (X), but (Y)"

Tags: expressions

> **Granted/Sure**, it's hot, **but** orders are orders.

En anglais, on emploie cette expression pour dire que « Là, je vous l'accorde, sur le point X, sans vouloir minimiser Y pour autant. » ou « J'ai beau reconnaître X, l'essentiel est tout de même Y. ».

Les expressions suivantes me sont familières, mais je m'interroge sur d'éventuelles nuances de sens entre les cinq. Ou, à tout le moins, sont-elles différentes de quelque manière que ce soit ?

Entre parenthèses, vaut-il mieux, ou non, placer une virgule immédiatement avant ou après le mot « d'accord » ou « certes » ?

> 1 : **D'accord**, il fait chaud, mais les ordres sont les ordres.
>
> 1+ : Il fait chaud, **d'accord**, mais les ordres sont les ordres.
>
> 2 : **Je te l'accorde**, il fait chaud, mais les ordres sont les ordres.
>
> 2+ : Il fait chaud, **je te l'accorde**, mais les ordres sont les ordres.
>
> 3 : **Certes**, il fait chaud, mais les ordres sont les ordres.
>
> 3+ : Il fait chaud, **certes**, mais les ordres sont les ordres.
>
> 4 : **Sûrement qu**'il fait chaud, mais les ordres sont les ordres.
>
> 5 : Il fait **peut-être** chaud, mais les ordres sont les ordres.

Comment: Pourquoi ne pas avoir inclus "Je vous l'accorde, il fait chaud..." alors qu'il fait parti de l'intro ? :)

Comment: @Random C'est bien noté. (ha-ha)

Comment: Since the last one with “peut-être” could be seen as expressing less than full agreement/accord with the premise about the heat, maybe you could get even further away from conceding the point by somehow working “ qu’il fasse chaud ou pas/froid” into the sentence.

Comment: @PapaPoule Je ne suis pas de ton avis sur ce coup-ci. En temps normal, le mot « peut-être » signifie bel et bien une éventualité, certes. Mais dans ce cas précis (dans l'expression « ... peut-être ... , mais ... »), je crois qu'il s'agit d’un fait indéniable. Par exemple : « Je suis **peut-être** une princesse, **mais** je ne m'estime pas heureux pour autant. ». Nul doute ici qu'elle est une princesse. Il en va d'ailleurs de même pour l'expression anglaise équivalente : « I **may/might** be a princess ... , **but** ... ». Qu'en penses-tu ? :)

Comment: My mistake, I think you're right!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**D'accord fonctionne comme oui (et non), comme une proposition, donc doit être séparé du reste par une virgule avant ou après (ou un point, ...):**

> D'accord, il fait chaud ...
>
> Il fait chaud, d'accord, ...

**Certes et peut-être peuvent être utilisés comme *d'accord* (règle précédente):**

> Certes, il fait chaud, ...
>
> Il fait chaud, certes, ...

***Certes* peut être utilisé comme n'importe quel adverbe, au sein d'une phrase, sans virgule:**

> Certes il fait chaud, ...
>
> Il fait certes chaud, ...
>
> Il fait peut-être chaud, ...
>
> Il fait chaud peut-être, ...

**Si on veut commencer par l'adverbe, on utilise plutôt la forme inversée:**

> Peut-être fait-il chaud, ...

**Les autres positions sont plus rares sans virgule, et se rapportent donc plutôt aux cas précédents (comme d'accord), donc avec une virgule:**

> Il fait chaud, certes, ...
>
> Peut-être, il fait chaud, ...

**Sûrement est dans le même cas:**

Comme d'accord:

> Sûrement, il fait chaud, ...
>
> Il fait chaud, sûrement, ...

Comme un adverbe classique:

> Il fait sûrement chaud, ...
>
> Sûrement fait-il chaud, ...

***Sûrement que* est du langage parlé, pas rédigé.**